# Java - parallel processing deadlock

Tags: java

I want try simple **Deadlock** example. I know the problem is in `(Thread t1 = new Thread() { )` and `( Thread t1 = new Thread() { )`.

> The value of the local variable t1 is not used.

But I can't fix it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String passenger1 ="pick passenger1";
    final String passenger2 ="pick passenger2"; 

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {      
        public void run(){          
        synchronized (passenger1) {

        System.out.println("Thread 1: locked passenger1 ");

        try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}
    System.out.println("Thread 1: waiting to get passenger 2 ");    
    synchronized (passenger2) {
        System.out.println("Thread 1: locked passenger 2");         
        }      }   }    };

   Thread t2 = new Thread() {

    public void run() { 
    synchronized (passenger2) {

       System.out.println("Thread 2: locked passenger2 ");

       try { Thread.sleep(100);}catch (Exception e) {}

   System.out.println("Thread 2: waiting to get passenger1 ");  

   synchronized (passenger1) {

        System.out.println("Thread 2: locked passenger1");  
                  }   
              }     
          }  
      };  
   } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried doing to fix this? Also you are never actually starting the threads.

Comment: When clicking 'Run'/'Debug' nothing happens

Comment: my program won't start when I click the Run

Comment: Probably because your code doesn't actually do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is self explanatory. You define a variable `t1` but you don't use it anywhere. If you don't use it, nothing will happen.

> my program won't start when I click the Run

Most likely what you intended was to start the thread, rather than just create an object.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread .... // creates a Thread object.
t1.start(); // actually starts the thread.
```